# Anti-diagonal matrix parallelism

Tags: matrix, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

How do I cross anti-diagonal of matrix and compute the anti-diagonal elements in the same time?

How can I loop the elements of an anti-diagonal in CUDA?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring on how you will loop throughout the biggest diagonal going from the lower left corner to the upper right corner, one way do it is to turn your anti-diagonal into an array. Since, you probably want to do some computation inside the GPU under this diagonal, before you copy the data from the CPU to the GPU you can do:

```
double diagonal [N];

for(int i = N - 1, j = 0; i >= 0, j < N ; i--, j++)
       diagonal = matrix[i][j];
```

Then you just send the array diagonal with size N (in one matrix of size N^2) to the GPU instead the whole matrix.

If you want to sent the whole matrix to the gpu and just perform operation on the anti-diagonal inside the gpu you can do:

```
__global__ gpuKernell(double **matrix, int N)
{
 int thread_id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    while(thread_id < N)
    {
       matrix[N-1-thread_id][thread_id] = // do something
       thread_id += blockDim.x * gridDim.x; 
    }
}
```